# Why does adding a tilde in front of a pattern match slow my function down?

Tags: haskell

I have two functions defined in a piece of haskell code:

```
lengthwtilde [] = 0
lengthwtilde ~(_:xs) = 1 + lengthwtilde xs

lengthwotilde [] = 0
lengthwotilde (_:xs) = 1 + lengthwotilde xs
```

When I test them both out in ghci (using `:set +s`), I find that `lengthwtilde` (the one with a tilde in front of the pattern match) performs significantly slower than `lengthwotilde` by about three seconds.

```
*Main> lengthwtilde [1..10000000]
10000000
(19.40 secs, 1731107132 bytes)
*Main> lengthwotilde [1..10000000]
10000000
(16.45 secs, 1531241716 bytes)
```

Why is this?

Comment: Have you take a look at this wiki page ? [Normally, if you pattern match using a constructor as part of the pattern, you have to evaluate any argument passed into that function to make sure it matches the pattern ... However, prepending a pattern with a tilde sign delays the evaluation of the value until the component parts are actually used](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness#Lazy_pattern_matching)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Adding a `~` in front of a pattern match makes that match *irrefutable*.  You can think of this as adding extra laziness to a pattern, so that it never fails to match unless that match is absolutely required for evaluation.  Here's a simple example:

```
Prelude> (\ (_:_) -> "non-empty") []
"*** Exception: <interactive>:2:2-23: Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda

Prelude> (\ ~(_:_) -> "oops") []
"oops"
```

With the irrefutable pattern match, even though the pattern match fails on an empty list, since no bound variables are evaluated, there's no error.  Essentially, the irrefutable pattern match transforms the function to:

```
\ xs -> let (_:_) = xs in "oops"
```

It's this extra wrapping of laziness that slows down your length function.  If you apply the same let-binding transform to `lengthwtilde` you get

```
lengthwtilde [] = 0
lengthwtilde xs' = let (_:xs) = xs' in 1 + lengthwtilde xs
```

Think about how this is evaluated.  At the top level, you get `1+lengthwtilde xs`.  But xs isn't even evaluated, since it's a let-bound variable.  So at the next step first `xs` is evaluated to determine it matches the second case of `lengthwtilde`, and the process repeats.

Contrast this to `lengthwotilde`.  In this function, the act of matching on the second case of the function forces the argument to be evaluated as well.  The end result is the same, but it's more efficient to be able to unwrap it sooner rather than leaving another thunk to be forced.

Technically `lengthwtilde` is slightly more complex: the argument is already *evaluated* in the second branch since that's how we determine which branch we're in, however it gets re-wrapped when passed into the recursive call.

It's useful to be able to see the produced core.  Here's the output of `lengthwotilde` (produced from `ghc -O0`:

```
Foo.lengthwotilde =
  \ (@ t_afD)
    (@ a_afE)
    ($dNum_afF :: GHC.Num.Num a_afE)
    (eta_B1 :: [t_afD]) ->
    letrec {
      lengthwotilde1_af2 [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: [t_afD] -> a_afE
      [LclId, Arity=1]
      lengthwotilde1_af2 =
        \ (ds_dgd :: [t_afD]) ->
          case ds_dgd of _ {
            [] -> GHC.Num.fromInteger @ a_afE $dNum_afF (__integer 0);
            : ds1_dge xs_af1 ->
              GHC.Num.+
                @ a_afE
                $dNum_afF
                (GHC.Num.fromInteger @ a_afE $dNum_afF (__integer 1))
                (lengthwotilde1_af2 xs_af1)
          }; } in
    lengthwotilde1_af2 eta_B1
```

Note the function `lengthwotilde1_af2` immediately does a `case` on the argument `ds_dgd` (this is the input list), and then recurses inside the case, forming a thunk (with some expansions):

```
1 + len [2..]
1 + (1 + len [3..])
1 + (1 + (1 + len [4..])
```

which ultimately requires the evaluation of
    1 + (1 + (1 + (1 + ..)))

Here's `lengthwtilde`

```
Foo.lengthwtilde =
  \ (@ t_afW)
    (@ a_afX)
    ($dNum_afY :: GHC.Num.Num a_afX)
    (eta_B1 :: [t_afW]) ->
    letrec {
      lengthwtilde1_afM [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: [t_afW] -> a_afX
      [LclId, Arity=1]
      lengthwtilde1_afM =
        \ (ds_dgh :: [t_afW]) ->
          case ds_dgh of wild_X9 {
            [] -> GHC.Num.fromInteger @ a_afX $dNum_afY (__integer 0);
            : ipv_sgv ipv1_sgw ->
              GHC.Num.+
                @ a_afX
                $dNum_afY
                (GHC.Num.fromInteger @ a_afX $dNum_afY (__integer 1))
                (lengthwtilde1_afM
                   (case wild_X9 of _ {
                      [] ->
                        (Control.Exception.Base.irrefutPatError
                           @ () "foo.hs:(3,1)-(4,42)|(_ : xs)")
                        `cast` (UnsafeCo () [t_afW] :: () ~# [t_afW]);
                      : ds1_dgk xs_aeH -> xs_aeH
                    }))
          }; } in
    lengthwtilde1_afM eta_B1
```

Evaluation of this forms a different thunk:

```
len [1..]
1 + (len (if null [1..] then error else [2..]))
1 + (len [2..])
1 + (1 + len (if null [2..] then error else [3..]))
```

which eventually results in the same chain of additions you got the first time, but with some extra logic to handle the irrefutable pattern failures.

Now, if you were running compiled code with any optimizations, ghc would almost certainly spot that the arguments couldn't possibly be null, since they're already evaluated and known to use the `(:)` constructor at this point.  And when I compile the code with `ghc -O2` and run it, both functions execute in the same amount of time.  They're both pretty bad, because either way results in a chain of thunks.  The standard definition of `length` is much better, as would be a good `foldl'` definition.